# Using components in nod_ modules folder in Angular5

Tags: web, angular5

I am developing a web site using AngularJS 5. I have downloaded a web template from  the internet. It has a login page. I want to edit the UI of that login page. When I searched for the login component, it is in a folder called @nebular in node_modules folder. 'src' folder does not contain 'login component' Then how can I edit login UI?

Answer (score 0):

The `node_modules` may contain the built version of the login. Copy the files from `@node_modules` and put it into your `src/app/` and import it as a `component`. Then, try editing the template file.

But I recommend to use the angular CLI to create a template rather than from a web-template. Then, make a components yourself for UI.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Should I keep the folder in node modules as it is?